# Fetching newly added data from mogoDB using socket.io (node,express,mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

How to fetch the newly added data to mongoDb using socket.io.

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
  foods: [
    {
      food: { type: Object, required: true },
      quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
    }
  ],
  user: {
    phoneNumber: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  },
  shopId:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [],
    
   },
   isCod:{
       type:Boolean,
       required: true,
       default:false
   },
   orderId:{
       type:String,
       required:true,
       default:"cod"
   },
   status:{
       type:String,
       required:true,
       default:"Order Placed"
   },
   isAccepted:{
       type:Boolean,
       required:true,
       default:false
   },
   deliveryCharge:{
     type:String,
     required:true
   }

},{ timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
```

I wanted to fetch the order data of particular shop using shopid

```
Order.find({ 'user.userId': req.user._id }).sort({'created_at':-1})
    .then(orders => {
      console.log(orders);
      res.render('user/order', {
        path: 'order',
        pageTitle: 'Your Orders',
        orders: orders
      });
    
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send("err");
    });
```

i have done fetching the data but i need to fetch the newly added data without refreshing the page. I found that socket.io is used for pushing the data but as iam new to it anyone please help me how to add that to my code.

Comment: Please share the code for the endpoint responsible for creating orders

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16YLWF5CZXoSDLeJkctMH3T1htgCRs0HBQH2xJo1svmg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: users will create the order to a particular shop